# Type of Authentication to Use for Remote Signing (Docusign)

Tags: docusignapi

As the title says, I wanted to know what type of Authentication to use for Remote Signing. I'm not sure whether to use Auth Code Grant or JWT Grant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remote signing, only the sender's API authentication matters. If the sending user will be present and able to enter their credentials as a part of the workflow, Auth Code Grant is recommended. If envelopes will be sent as a part of a "background" or "automated" process, JWT grant will likely be necessary.